# Nancy TinyIoC error after RavenDB client lib upgrade

Tags: ravendb, tinyioc, nancy

I'm getting this error after upgrading the RavenDB client libs from 2.5.2666 to 2.5.2851

```
Method 'DeleteByIndexAsync' in type 'Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddedAsyncServerClient' from assembly 'Raven.Client.Embedded, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593' does not have an implementation.
```

Seems to be breaking on line 3065 from the stack trace but I'm not sure why:

```
Line 3064:                var concreteTypes = from type in types
Line 3065:                                    where type.IsClass() && (type.IsAbstract() == false) && (type != this.GetType() && (type.DeclaringType != this.GetType()) && (!type.IsGenericTypeDefinition()))
Line 3066:                                    select type;
```

TinyIoC is set to auto scan for all dependencies:

```
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
        RavenDbConfiguration.ConfigureStore(container);
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Bootstrap(container);
    }
```

and if I take that line out which calls base then the app starts working again, but falls over later where I haven't registered a specific dependency, so I'd rather let it keep on autoscanning and just get to the bottom of this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a problem with .NET framework versions to me. Can you use .net framework 4.5 if you are not already? If you are, ensure your packages are all .net 45.

Comment: I have fixed this kind of error by cleaning the /bin directory for my project.